# Проблема с созданием виртуальной машины

Tags: virtualbox, bios

Создаю самую обычную машину Linux Ubuntu в VirtualBox, но при запуске возникает ошибка (0x80004005). Ранее не работала с этой виртуалкой (грубо говоря, первый запуск после установки). Решаю, что проблема в том, что вин нужно в биосе сделать что-то вроде разрешения на виртуальные такие действия (кажется так: Advanced BIOS Features). НО, вот туть то и вопрос, при попытке запустить bios ноутбук выдаёт ошибку 0xc000000f. Что же мне тогда делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: Какая у вас ОС ? Для начала установите все обновления системы (если windows то в том числе не обязательные) затем установите последнюю версию VirtualBox. В windows с внедрением Hyper-V в профессиональные версии а также WSL теперь постоянно меняются правила "игры" по этому разные версии VirtualBox работают на разных сборках Windows, что привносит немного хауса :)

Comment: VirtualBox надо выбросить и взять VMware Player, VirtualBox в тепленьких ручках Oracle превратился в какое-то недоразумение

Comment: ОС стоит Win10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

В CMOS Setup для VirtualBox требуются только включенные опции VTd и VTx (если они есть). Как правило, по-умолчанию они включены, либо как настройки отсутствуют совсем. Эти технологии присутствуют во всех современных CPU от AMD и Intel. Другие опции CMOS setup на работу VirtualBox повлиять не могут.

0x80004005 - это неопределенная ошибка. Как правило, связанны с отсутствием каких-либо файлов или отсутствием доступа на их чтение. Здесь есть небольшой гайд: https://comhub.ru/0x80004005/ . Но неопределённые ошибки они на то и неопределённые, потому что могут иметь множество разных причин в их проявлении.